# ApplePay canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks Always Returns False

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, applepay

I am trying to incorporate ApplePay into my Cordova 7.0.1 application running XCode 8.3.3, but I can't get the code below to work.  It returns false each time even though I have a mastercard and visa setup in my wallet.  I have called CapitalOne and Citi to confirm that the cards are properly setup for ApplePay.  Any advise to get the code to recognize the cards would be much appreciated!

```
supportedPaymentNetworks = @[PKPaymentNetworkVisa, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard, PKPaymentNetworkAmex];

if ([PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks:supportedPaymentNetworks]) {
    NSLog(@"Supported card found");
} else {
    NSLog(@"No supported card found");
}
```

Comment: Do you have parental controls for purchasing on?

Comment: I have restrictions disabled under General - Restrictions.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah. Not sure why it's not working for you if that's off, sorry!

Comment: Any other suggestions from anyone out there?  This has really got me stumped.  I have additionally tried to delete all cards from the Wallet and re-add them one at a time.  The app seemingly fails to see them.  Unfortunately, there isn't a way to have any visibility of what [PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks] is doing and why it fails.

Comment: Also, this is on an iPhone 6S running iOS 10.3.2

Comment: Anyone with any insight?

Comment: @Kal, I'm also having the same issue, I do have multiple cards added to my Wallet. But still canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks is always returning false. Did you find the solution for the same ? Any luck ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple Pay was not turned ON in the Capabilities section of target settings in Xcode.

Comment: I set Apple Pay to ON in the Capabilities section of target settings in Xcode. But it's always return false

Comment: @DuyenHangKim Do you fix that issue?

Comment: Make sure it is set on the build setting for the type of build you are doing. It is possible, for example, to turn it on for a production build but not for a debug build.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve if you set martchant id in AppName.entitlements file.
If you already set martchant id in AppName.entitlements file, i wanna know how you made martchant id and certificate file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Finally i found that i forgot to load Entitlements.plist file in iOS project setting. you can find more detail in

[How to integrate Apple Pay in Xamarin Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55999193/how-to-integrate-apple-pay-in-xamarin-forms/56036357#56036357)

Hope this will help

Comment: How do you fix that?

Comment: please see the details in this link   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55999193/how-to-integrate-apple-pay-in-xamarin-forms/56036357#56036357