# Apple Pay with WorldPay integration - extracting payload

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, applepay, worldpay

On Xamarin Forms, I am trying to send an Apple Pay payload to [WorldPay](https://developer.worldpay.com/docs/wpg/mobilewallets/applepay) (payment gateway). It has a guide on what the request should look like, and here is a short snippet:

```
<APPLEPAY-SSL>
    <header>
      <ephemeralPublicKey>AAAA...</ephemeralPublicKey>
      <publicKeyHash>AAAA...</publicKeyHash>
      <transactionId>AAAA...</transactionId>
    </header>
    <signature>AAAA...</signature>
    <version>EC_v1</version>
    <data>AAAA...</data>
  </APPLEPAY-SSL>
```

I need to extract this mandatory data from the [PKPayment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/passkit.pkpayment?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) object that I get in the below override

```
public override void DidAuthorizePayment(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController controller, PKPayment payment, Action<PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus> completion)
    {
        completion(obj: PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.Success);
    }
```

The only examples I found on how to handle this object, are to use a 3rd party SDK (stripe) which extracts just the ID and Token, and not all that I need.

My current code is identical to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55999193/how-to-integrate-apple-pay-in-xamarin-forms%C2%A0).

Please let me know how can I get the data world pay requires using apple pay in Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

Step 1: Do not use an emulator! Emulators do not have a payload!

Step 2: Payload is inside `PKPayment.Token.PaymentData`

Step 3: Convert it to string: `PaymentData.ToString()`

End Result: `string payload = payment.Token.PaymentData.ToString();`
Result will be in JSON format and will contain everything that is required in the question.